# Count the total (N) of duplicates in a column

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm attempting to count the total number of duplicates in a column (not the individual duplicates).

```
from outputs
GROUP BY journal_id
HAVING ( COUNT(doi) > 1 )
WHERE journal_id = 1
```

SQL TABLE

```
doi   journal_id   
123       1
123       2
123       1
124       1
```

The expected answer is 2

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain how the "2" is calculated.

Comment: Why not count by individual duplicates and subtract one? Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Syntax error. WHERE should be before GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

The number of entire row duplicates can be calculated by taking the total number of rows and subtracting the number of distinct rows:

```
select a.cnt_all - d.cnt_individual
from (select count(*) as cnt_all
      from outputs
     ) a cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt_individual
      from (select distinct *
            from outputs
           ) d
     ) d;
```

If you know your columns and your database supports multiple arguments to `count(distinct)`, this can be radically simplified to:

```
select count(*) - count(distinct doi, journal_id)
from outputs;
```

Or, if your database doesn't support this:

```
select sum(cnt - 1)
from (select doi, journal_id, count(*) as cnt
      from outputs
      group by doi, journal_id
     ) o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sum up the count of the individual duplicates by journal id.

```
SELECT
  SUM(COUNT(doi)) AS total_duplicates
from
  outputs
WHERE
  journal_id = 1
GROUP BY
  journal_id
HAVING
  (COUNT(doi) > 1)
```